# Two datasets with different column names but same ID column. How to get values from one column in second dataset based on the matching ID col in R?

Tags: r

I have two datasets in my environment. One is in long format and one is in wide format. Say I have something similar to the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  rater_type = c("Direct", "Direct", "Other", "Other", "Peer", "Peer"), 
  year = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), 
  m1 = c(4, 5, NA, 4.5, 3, 4), 
  m2 = c(4, 5, NA, 3.5, 5, 4)
)
```

and

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  cohort = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  rater_type = c("Direct", "Direct", "Other", "Other", "Peer", "Peer"),
  competency_new = c("m1", "m1", "m1", "m2", "m2", "m2"),
  year = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  score = c(4, 5, NA, 3.5, 5, 4)
)
```

What I'm looking to do is bring in the values from the `cohort` column into df1 based on the matching value in the `ID` column across these two datasets. Ideal output would look like:

```
df3 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  cohort = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  rater_type = c("Direct", "Direct", "Other", "Other", "Peer", "Peer"),
  year = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  m1 = c(4, 5, NA, 4.5, 3, 4),
  m2 = c(4, 5, NA, 3.5, 5, 4)
)
```

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Maybe a simple join `library(dplyr); left_join(df1, df2, by=c("ID", "rater_type", "year")) %>% select(-c(competency_new, score))`?

Comment: `library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lookup_cohort <- df2 %>%
  distinct(score, cohort) %>%  
  drop_na(score) %>%           
  deframe()                    

df1 %>%
  mutate(cohort = map_vec(m1, ~ lookup_cohort[as.character(.x)]),
         cohort = if_else(is.na(cohort), map_vec(m2, ~ lookup_cohort[as.character(.x)]), cohort), .before = 2)`